# Including any new header makes the project give irrelevant errors

Tags: c++, visual-c++, header

Im working on an open-source project "powder toy" and manged to compile it under msvc. Run fine. But when I include a new header in air.h, compiling gives errors such as:

'GetUserNameA! is not a member of 'SaveInfo' in  GameController.cpp file.

and

syntax error: '::' in BitmapBrush.h file. ---> pointing min - max of windows.

Both files are untouched and does not have anything in common with the header I added:

Aux_cl.h  ---> added to beginning of air.h

this header has just opencl headers which powdertoy does not have them in any of other cpp/h files.

What am I doing wrong?
If I delete the inclusion of Aux_cl, project compiles fine even with the opencl bindings in the Aux_cl(this not bind to anything, just compiled separately I think)

**Edit: When I add "#undef min" and "#undef GetUserName" before those error points, it compiles file, I wonder how it works without my header files included before.**

Edit2: Should I add #def blabla just after the functions after those #undef blabla ?

Here is the

Air.h:

```
#ifndef AIR_H
#define AIR_H
#include "Config.h"
#include "Aux_cl.h"

class Simulation;

class Air
{
public:
    Simulation & sim;
    int airMode;
    float ambientAirTemp;
    Aux_cl *gpu;
    //Arrays from the simulation
    unsigned char (*bmap)[XRES/CELL];
    unsigned char (*emap)[XRES/CELL];
    float (*fvx)[XRES/CELL];
    float (*fvy)[XRES/CELL];
    //
    float vx[YRES/CELL][XRES/CELL];
    float ovx[YRES/CELL][XRES/CELL];
    float vy[YRES/CELL][XRES/CELL];
    float ovy[YRES/CELL][XRES/CELL];
    float pv[YRES/CELL][XRES/CELL];
    float opv[YRES/CELL][XRES/CELL];
    float hv[YRES/CELL][XRES/CELL];
    float ohv[YRES/CELL][XRES/CELL]; // Ambient Heat
    unsigned char bmap_blockair[YRES/CELL][XRES/CELL];
    unsigned char bmap_blockairh[YRES/CELL][XRES/CELL];
    float kernel[9];
    void make_kernel(void);
    void update_airh(void);
    void update_air(void);
    void Clear();
    void ClearAirH();
    void Invert();
    Air(Simulation & sim);
};

#endif
```

Aux_cl.h:

```
#pragma once

#define __CL_ENABLE_EXCEPTIONS
#include<CL\opencl.h>
#include<CL\cl.hpp>
#include<CL\cl.h>
#include"ClKernelFactory.h"   // this has nothing but string variables and simple function. No other includes about windows or powder toy
#define FIRST_COMPUTE_DEVICE 0
/*
Simple compute helper class for your heavy work loads.
Uses OpenCL 1.2 headers so you may need an up-to-date CPU or an AMD-GPU for now.
Instances of this classes are different contexts and should be compiled serially.
Computation can be concurrent without fear.

Writer: Huseyin Tugrul BUYUKISIK
*/

class Aux_cl
{

public:
    cl::Context *context;
    std::vector<cl::Program::Sources> sources;
    std::vector<cl::Program> programs;
    std::vector<std::vector<cl::Device>> devicesCPU;
    std::vector<std::vector<cl::Device>> devicesGPU;

    cl::CommandQueue cq;
    std::vector<cl::Buffer> buffers;
    std::vector<cl::Memory> memories;
    std::vector<cl::NDRange> globalRanges;
    std::vector<cl::NDRange> localRanges;
    std::vector<cl::NDRange> referenceRanges;

    std::vector<std::string> kernelFunctionsToBeCompiled;
    std::vector<std::string> kernelNames;
    std::vector<std::string> bufferNames;
    std::vector<cl::Kernel> kernelFunctions; 
    std::vector<std::pair<std::vector<int>,int>> bufferTargetsForKernels; // {500}, {501, 502},{530} ... --> buffer ids
                                                            // 0,1,2,... --> kernel ids
    std::vector<std::pair<int,std::vector<std::string>>> bufferDefinitions;
    std::vector<std::pair<int,std::string>> kernelDefinitions;
    std::vector<cl::Platform> platforms;

    cl_context_properties *context_properties;
    std::string CPU_GPU; //"gpu" "GPU"  "graphics" "GRAPHICS" "cpu" "CPU"
    int kernelId;
    int bufferId;
    int numberOfCPU;
    int numberOfGPU;
    int first_CPU_platform;
    int first_CPU_device;
    int first_GPU_platform;
    int first_GPU_device;

    int second_CPU_platform;
    int second_CPU_device;
    int second_GPU_platform;
    int second_GPU_device;


    int which_one;
    static const int FIRST=0, SECOND=1, THIRD=2, FOURTH=3, OMG=4; 
    Aux_cl(std::string gpu_or_cpu, int whichOne)
    {

        which_one=whichOne;
        CPU_GPU=gpu_or_cpu;
        kernelId=0;
        bufferId=0;
        numberOfGPU=0;
        numberOfCPU=0;
        cl::Platform::get(&platforms);

        for(int i=0;i<platforms.size();i++)
        {
            devicesCPU.push_back(std::vector<cl::Device>());  // one device list for each platform (AMD, NVIDIA, INTEL, ...)
        }

        for(int i=0;i<platforms.size();i++)
        {
            devicesGPU.push_back(std::vector<cl::Device>());  // one device list for each platform (AMD, NVIDIA, INTEL, ...)
        }


        //selecting the platform that has a cpu or gpu specified in construction
        for(int i=0;i<platforms.size();i++)
        {
            platforms[i].getDevices(CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU,&devicesCPU[i]); 
        }
        //selecting the platform that has a cpu or gpu specified in construction
        for(int i=0;i<platforms.size();i++)
        {
            platforms[i].getDevices(CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU,&devicesGPU[i]); 
        }


        //searching device lists for a gpu or cpu (as selected in construction)
        for(int i=0;i<platforms.size();i++)
        {
            bool notFoundYet=true;
            bool notFoundYet2=true;

            if(devicesCPU[i].size()>0)
            for(int j=0;j<devicesCPU[i].size();j++)
            {
                if(notFoundYet)
                {
                    first_CPU_platform=i;
                    first_CPU_device=j;
                    notFoundYet=false;
                }

                if((!notFoundYet)&&(notFoundYet2))
                {
                    second_CPU_platform=i;
                    second_CPU_device=j;
                    notFoundYet2=false;
                }
                numberOfCPU++;
            }
        }
        //searching device lists for a gpu or cpu (as selected in construction)
        for(int i=0;i<platforms.size();i++)
        {
            bool notFoundYet=true;bool notFoundYet2=true;
            if(devicesGPU[i].size()>0)
            for(int j=0;j<devicesCPU[i].size();j++)
            {
                if(notFoundYet)
                {
                    first_GPU_platform=i;
                    first_GPU_device=j;
                    notFoundYet=false;
                }

                if((!notFoundYet)&&(notFoundYet2))
                {
                    second_CPU_platform=i;
                    second_CPU_device=j;
                    notFoundYet2=false;
                }
                numberOfGPU++;
            }
        }


    };

    void AddKernelFromFactory(KernelIngredients ki)
    {
        AddKernelToPool(ki.bodyOfKernel, ki.nameOfKernel,
                        ki.globalX,ki.globalY,
                        ki.localX,ki.localY);
    }

    void AddKernelToPool(std::string KernelItself, std::string KernelName,
                         int GlobalRangeX,int GlobalRangeY,
                         int LocalRangeX,int LocalRangeY)
    {
        if(GlobalRangeY!=0)
        {
            kernelFunctionsToBeCompiled.push_back(KernelItself);
            kernelNames.push_back(KernelName);
            globalRanges.push_back(cl::NDRange(GlobalRangeX,GlobalRangeY));
            localRanges.push_back(cl::NDRange(LocalRangeX,LocalRangeY));
            referenceRanges.push_back(cl::NDRange(0,0));
            kernelDefinitions.push_back(std::pair<int,std::string>(kernelId,KernelName));
            kernelId++;
        }
        else
        {
            kernelFunctionsToBeCompiled.push_back(KernelItself);
            kernelNames.push_back(KernelName);
            globalRanges.push_back(cl::NDRange(GlobalRangeX));
            localRanges.push_back(cl::NDRange(LocalRangeX));
            referenceRanges.push_back(cl::NDRange(0));
            kernelDefinitions.push_back(std::pair<int,std::string>(kernelId,KernelName));
            kernelId++;

        }
    };

    void AddBufferToPool(std::string nameOfBuffer,std::string typeOfBuffer, int sizeOfBuffer)
    {
        // 0,{"a","float","8192"}
        std::vector<std::string> BufferNameTypeSize;
        BufferNameTypeSize.push_back(nameOfBuffer);
        BufferNameTypeSize.push_back(typeOfBuffer);
        BufferNameTypeSize.push_back(std::to_string(sizeOfBuffer));
        bufferDefinitions.push_back(std::pair<int,std::vector<std::string>>(bufferId,BufferNameTypeSize));
        bufferNames.push_back(BufferNameTypeSize[0]);
        bufferId++;
    }



    void WireBuffersToSingleKernel(std::vector<std::string> buffers, std::string theKernel )
    {

        std::vector<int> bufferL;
        int index=-1;
        for(int i=0;i<buffers.size();i++)
        {

            for(int j=0;j<bufferDefinitions.size();j++)
            {
                if(bufferDefinitions[j].second[0]==(buffers[i]))
                {
                    bufferL.push_back(bufferDefinitions[j].first);
                }
            }

            for(int k=0;k<kernelDefinitions.size();k++)
            {
                if(kernelDefinitions[k].second==(theKernel))
                {
                    index=kernelDefinitions[k].first;
                }
            }
        }
        bufferTargetsForKernels.push_back(std::pair<std::vector<int>,int>(bufferL,index)); 
        // buffers {23,33,10,1,40} for the kernel {3} as a pair

    }


    void compile()
    {
        if(which_one==FIRST)
        {
            //clGetPlatformIDs(1,&platform_id,NULL);
            if((CPU_GPU==("CPU"))||(CPU_GPU==("cpu")))
            {
                cl_context_properties properties[] = { CL_CONTEXT_PLATFORM, (cl_context_properties)(platforms[first_CPU_platform])(), 0};
                context=new cl::Context(CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU, properties);
            }

            if((CPU_GPU==("GPU"))||(CPU_GPU==("gpu")))
            {
                cl_context_properties properties[] = { CL_CONTEXT_PLATFORM, (cl_context_properties)(platforms[first_GPU_platform])(), 0};
                context=new cl::Context(CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, properties);
            }
        }

        if(which_one==SECOND)
        {
            //clGetPlatformIDs(1,&platform_id,NULL);
            if((CPU_GPU==("CPU"))||(CPU_GPU==("cpu")))
            {
                cl_context_properties properties[] = { CL_CONTEXT_PLATFORM, (cl_context_properties)(platforms[second_CPU_platform])(), 0};
                context=new cl::Context(CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU, properties);
            }

            if((CPU_GPU==("GPU"))||(CPU_GPU==("gpu")))
            {
                cl_context_properties properties[] = { CL_CONTEXT_PLATFORM, (cl_context_properties)(platforms[second_GPU_platform])(), 0};
                context=new cl::Context(CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, properties);
            }
        }
        /*
        for(int i=0;i<platforms.size();i++)
        {
            devices[i]=context[0].getInfo<CL_CONTEXT_DEVICES>(); // device lists are created
        }
        */


        if(which_one==FIRST)
        {

            for(int i=0;i<kernelFunctionsToBeCompiled.size();i++) 
            {
                sources.push_back(cl::Program::Sources()); 
                sources[i].push_back(std::make_pair(kernelFunctionsToBeCompiled[i].data(),kernelFunctionsToBeCompiled[i].length()));
                programs.push_back(cl::Program(context[0],sources[i]));

                if((CPU_GPU==("CPU"))||(CPU_GPU==("cpu")))
                {
                    programs[i].build(devicesCPU[first_CPU_platform]);
                }

                if((CPU_GPU==("GPU"))||(CPU_GPU==("gpu")))
                {
                    programs[i].build(devicesGPU[first_GPU_platform]);
                }

                kernelFunctions.push_back(cl::Kernel(programs[i],kernelNames[i].data()));
            }

            if((CPU_GPU==("CPU"))||(CPU_GPU==("cpu")))
            {
                    cq=cl::CommandQueue(context[0],devicesCPU[first_CPU_platform][first_CPU_device]);
            }
            if((CPU_GPU==("GPU"))||(CPU_GPU==("gpu")))
            {
                    cq=cl::CommandQueue(context[0],devicesGPU[first_GPU_platform][first_GPU_device]);
            }


        }

        if(which_one==SECOND)
        {

            for(int i=0;i<kernelFunctionsToBeCompiled.size();i++) 
            {
                sources.push_back(cl::Program::Sources()); 
                sources[i].push_back(std::make_pair(kernelFunctionsToBeCompiled[i].data(),kernelFunctionsToBeCompiled[i].length()));
                programs.push_back(cl::Program(context[0],sources[i]));

                if((CPU_GPU==("CPU"))||(CPU_GPU==("cpu")))
                {
                    programs[i].build(devicesCPU[second_CPU_platform]);
                }

                if((CPU_GPU==("GPU"))||(CPU_GPU==("gpu")))
                {
                    programs[i].build(devicesGPU[second_GPU_platform]);
                }

                kernelFunctions.push_back(cl::Kernel(programs[i],kernelNames[i].data()));
            }

            if((CPU_GPU==("CPU"))||(CPU_GPU==("cpu")))
            {
                    cq=cl::CommandQueue(context[0],devicesCPU[second_CPU_platform][second_CPU_device]);
            }
            if((CPU_GPU==("GPU"))||(CPU_GPU==("gpu")))
            {
                    cq=cl::CommandQueue(context[0],devicesGPU[second_GPU_platform][second_GPU_device]);
            }


        }


        for(int i=0;i<bufferDefinitions.size();i++)
        {
            int sizeOfBuffer=std::stoi(bufferDefinitions[i].second[2]);
            if(bufferDefinitions[i].second[1]=="float")
            {
                buffers.push_back(cl::Buffer(context[0],CL_MEM_READ_WRITE,sizeof(cl_float)*sizeOfBuffer));
            }
            if(bufferDefinitions[i].second[1]=="int")
            {
                buffers.push_back(cl::Buffer(context[0],CL_MEM_READ_WRITE,sizeof(cl_int)*sizeOfBuffer));
            }
            if(bufferDefinitions[i].second[1]=="double")
            {
                buffers.push_back(cl::Buffer(context[0],CL_MEM_READ_WRITE,sizeof(cl_double)*sizeOfBuffer));
            }
            if(bufferDefinitions[i].second[1]=="long")
            {
                buffers.push_back(cl::Buffer(context[0],CL_MEM_READ_WRITE,sizeof(cl_long)*sizeOfBuffer));
            }

            if(bufferDefinitions[i].second[1]=="char")
            {
                buffers.push_back(cl::Buffer(context[0],CL_MEM_READ_WRITE,sizeof(cl_char)*sizeOfBuffer));
            }

        }

        for(int i=0;i<bufferTargetsForKernels.size();i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<bufferTargetsForKernels[i].first.size();j++)
            {
                kernelFunctions[bufferTargetsForKernels[i].second].setArg(j,buffers[bufferTargetsForKernels[i].first[j]]);
            }
        }   

    }

    void SelectClBuffersToWriteOnThem()
    {

    }

    void SelectClBuffersToReadFromThem()
    {

    }

    void WriteToClFromCPP(std::string clArrayName,float *arrayCPP)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<buffers.size();i++)
        {
            if(bufferNames[i]==clArrayName)
            {
                cq.finish();
                cq.enqueueWriteBuffer(buffers[i],CL_TRUE,0,sizeof(cl_float)*(std::atoi(bufferDefinitions[i].second[2].data())),arrayCPP);

                cq.finish();
            }
        }
    }


    void WriteToClFrom2DCPP(std::string clArrayName,static float *arrayCPP) // 2D array = contiguous?
    {       

        for(int i=0;i<buffers.size();i++)
        {
            if(bufferNames[i]==clArrayName)
            {
                cq.finish();
                cq.enqueueWriteBuffer(buffers[i],CL_TRUE,0,sizeof(cl_float)*(std::atoi(bufferDefinitions[i].second[2].data())), arrayCPP);
                cq.finish();

            }
        }
    }

    void WriteToClFrom2DCPP(std::string clArrayName,static char *arrayCPP) // 2D array = contiguous?
    {       

        for(int i=0;i<buffers.size();i++)
        {
            if(bufferNames[i]==clArrayName)
            {
                cq.finish();
                cq.enqueueWriteBuffer(buffers[i],CL_TRUE,0,sizeof(cl_char)*(std::atoi(bufferDefinitions[i].second[2].data())), arrayCPP);
                cq.finish();

            }
        }
    }




    void ReadFromClToCPP(std::string clArrayName, float *arrayCPP)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<buffers.size();i++)
        {
            if(bufferNames[i]==clArrayName)
            {
                cq.finish();
                cq.enqueueReadBuffer(buffers[i],CL_TRUE,0,sizeof(cl_float)*(std::atoi(bufferDefinitions[i].second[2].data())),arrayCPP);
                cq.finish();
            }
        }
    }

    void ReadFromClTo2DCPP(std::string clArrayName,static float *arrayCPP) // 2D arrays are contiguous?
    {       
        for(int i=0;i<buffers.size();i++)
        {
            if(bufferNames[i]==clArrayName)
            {
                cq.finish();
                cq.enqueueReadBuffer(buffers[i],CL_TRUE,0,sizeof(cl_float)*(std::atoi(bufferDefinitions[i].second[2].data())), arrayCPP);
                cq.finish();
            }
        }
    }

    void ReadFromClTo2DCPP(std::string clArrayName,static char *arrayCPP) // 2D arrays are contiguous?
    {       
        for(int i=0;i<buffers.size();i++)
        {
            if(bufferNames[i]==clArrayName)
            {
                cq.finish();
                cq.enqueueReadBuffer(buffers[i],CL_TRUE,0,sizeof(cl_char)*(std::atoi(bufferDefinitions[i].second[2].data())), arrayCPP);
                cq.finish();
            }
        }
    }


    std::vector<int> computeList;

    void MakeKernelListToRun(std::vector<std::string> listOfKernels)
    {
        computeList.clear();
        for(int j=0;j<listOfKernels.size();j++)
        {
            for(int i=0;i<kernelNames.size();i++)
            {
                if(listOfKernels[j]==kernelNames[i])
                {
                    computeList.push_back(i);
                }
            }
        }
    }



    void ComputeList()
    {
        for(int i=0;i<computeList.size();i++)
        {
            cq.enqueueNDRangeKernel(kernelFunctions[computeList[i]],referenceRanges[computeList[i]],globalRanges[computeList[i]],localRanges[computeList[i]]);
        }
    }



    void Compute(std::string kernelName)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<kernelNames.size();i++)
        {
            if(kernelName==kernelNames[i])
            {
                cq.enqueueNDRangeKernel(kernelFunctions[i],referenceRanges[i],globalRanges[i],localRanges[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    void releaseClResources()
    {
        cq.finish();
        // opencl c++ bindings wrapper deletes / releases automatically when of no use
    }

    ~Aux_cl(void)
    {
        delete context;
    };
};
```

Last edit:

In KernelIngredients.cpp there is only #include "KernelIngredients.h"

In KernelIngredients.h there is no inclusion

In ClKernelFactory.h there is only #include "KernelIngredients.h"

In ClKernelFactory.cpp there is only #include "ClKernelFactory.h"

In Aux_cl.cpp there is only #include "Aux_cl.h"

In Aux_cl.h there is only opencl inclusions (i wish these dont use the windows things that clashes with min() and GetUserName() :S )

In Air.h there are  #include "Aux_cl.h" and #include"ClKernelFactory.h"

Comment: In KernelIngredients.cpp there is only #include "KernelIngredients.h"

In KernelIngredients.h there is no inclusion

In ClKernelFactory.h there is only #include "KernelIngredients.h"

In ClKernelFactory.cpp there is only #include "ClKernelFactory.h"

In Aux_cl.cpp there is only #include "Aux_cl.h"

In Aux_cl.h there is only opencl inclusions (i wish these dont use the windows things :S )

In Air.h there are  #include "Aux_cl.h" and #include"ClKernelFactory.h"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like one of the headers included indirectly via `air.h` is defining a macro which conflicts with a symbol name elsewhere in the sources. The macro basically defines a search-replace operation which is carried out by the preprocessor, before the compiler kicks in.

Take this example:

```
/** header_1.h **/
void foo(){ std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl; }

/** header_2.h **/
#define foo bar

/** main.cpp **/
#include "header_1.h"
#include "header_2.h"

int main() {
  foo();
}
```

Compiling `main.cpp` will give you an error that the method `bar` is not defined, since the preprocessor replaced all occurrences of `foo` appearing after the point `header_2.h`was included with `bar`.

Comment: So this is about cl.hpp has windows.h inclusion just as powdertoy.h has the same or similar windows.h / winnt.h things that clash? How can I solve this without changing cl.hpp ? Aux_cl includes the cl.hpp.

Comment: Somewhere in your include hierarchy a header is defining the macro `GetUserName`, while somewhere else in your include hierarchy a header is defining the symbol `GetUserName`. A good way to find out where i.e. `GetUserName` is previously defined as a macro is to add another `#define GetUserName` at a lower level in the hierarchy. Your compiler should then warn you that you are redefining the macro `GetUserName` and tell you where it was previously defined. Or you could just grep through the source tree clearly.

Comment: So when I edit an opensource project, I need to know what am I including. Maybe I can solve with using #undef min and #undef GetUserName just after inclusion of opencl am I right?

Comment: This is unrelated to the project being an opensource one. When you work with a codebase that has macros, you always have the risk of macros conflicting with symbols. You can read http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/inline-vs-macros.html and the there linked evil#1, evil#2, evil#3, and evil#4 to find out more about what issues macros can cause. As for the fix, ideally rename the macro or the symbol. `#undef` is still potentially very dangerous, because some other code lower down in the hierarchy might depend on the macro being defined.